# VB.NET adding Rows and columns

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm after a way to add multiple amounts in different columns in a certain date_code, i've used the select sum to add amounts in a single column, but i have no an idea on how to add multiple column rows up, if you get what I mean, my sql database is as follows:

```
  Date       amount1    amount2    amount3    amount4    amount5
 02/10/2014    2            3           6           0           5
 02/10/2014    3            1           2           0           3
 02/10/2014    0            4           6           6           2
 02/10/2014    2            0           9           3           6
 02/10/2014    7            0           8           2           9
```

Im need the total of all amounts in the same date range.

Total would be: 71

Any help would be great,

Many Thanks,
Pete

This is the code i've got so far which adds the amount, but only in one column:

```
connect() cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(amount1) FROM sqlccmbuildtimecount WHERE datevar = '" & temp_day & "/" & temp_month & "/" & temp_year & "'"
    endvalue.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar() disconnect()
```

i've set temp_day to "02", temp_month to "10" and temp_year to "2014"

Comment: You have to be more specific. What objects and tools are you using?  At least a portion of your code would be nice.

Comment: i've altered my question, cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question, but could you just do "SELECT SUM(amount1) + SUM(amount2) + ... FROM ..." ?

Answer (score 0):

Sum is not 71, should be 89

Like the_lotus said,

do:

```
SELECT SUM(amount1) + SUM(amount2) + SUM(amount3) + SUM(amount4) + SUM(amount5) FROM sqlccmbuildtimecount WHERE datevar = '" & temp_day & "/" & temp_month & "/" & temp_year & "'"
```